# Defer loading of images without the use of JS

Tags: html

I want to defer the loading of images in an HTML file until after all other assets have loaded or for a set amount of time. I would like to do this without JS.

I already use a deferred image loading technique that uses JS in our web app. However, a version of this app runs without JS and I'd like to have the same functionality if possible. I posted this in the hopes there may be some little known HTML5 attribute I can use for this. Any workaround are welcome.

**Load priotity**

If possible, it would be good to break up the image loading into blocks. I'm ok even if it's all just one block as well.

1. All HTML / CSS
2. Image block
3. Image block

**Note :** I've already looked into having lazy loading only for the JS app and having the image load right away for my pure HTML version ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708833/how-to-lazy-load-images-while-still-displaying-for-people-with-javascript-disabl?rq=1)), that's my fallback.

Answer (score 3):

If you are targeting the Chrome browser, chromium has introduced a native image lazy loading so that means you don't need to install any further 3rd party library for this.

Using native image lazy loading, you should add `loading` attribute in the `img` html tag like this :

```
<img src="..." loading="lazy" width="200" height="200">
```

Also make sure that you have the latest version of Chrome browser installed.

For further details please go through this reference: https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading#image-loading

Hopefully it could be helpful.