# Show an alternative image while another image loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I have a div with a background image like this:

```
<div class="carousel-image" 
     style="background: url(img/background.gif) no-repeat center center;">
</div>
```

When I load my webpage, there's an annoying second of blank background while my large background.gif image loads. How can I go about having an alternative image that loads quickly and is replaced as soon as the background.gif image is ready to take its place?

Comment: Would like to modify your code if you have any.

Comment: please provide some code !

Comment: What you want to do is called "image lazy loading"
Have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582739/lazy-loading-images

Comment: Thanks Charles -- seems like I can use this to solve my problem!

Comment: It seems like lazy loading is usually done with an <image> where its src is swapped out with another -- how would I do this by changing style= to something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have two solutions.

1. You can use lazy loading of your image. For this solution, have a look to this question on stackoverflow: [Lazy loading images how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033596/lazy-loading-images-how)
2. And if your image is small enough, you can use a [data URI](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) instead of a link to your image. This will embed directly your image inside the html code, so there is nothing more to load. Here is a description on how you can convert your image to data URI: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/convert-an-image-to-a-data-uri-with-your-browser/

The first solution answers your question. The second one does not, but it is an other solution to the same problem.